# Struct Unpack with Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct

I am trying to convert my code to **Python 3** and I am having a problem about **Struct** while using problem. When I don't use variable while unpacking it gives me the result which I want, but when I use variable it doesn't give me the result that it needs to give.

I use def named "**dataReceived**" to get the data from socket. And I unpack it with struct.

Code with no variable (it gives true result) (result is 2) (packet is same with the packet that I get from socket):

```
packetFormat = unpack('!b', b'\x02\x01]\x00\x1c\x01\x01\xb0\x00\taMtIyfKal\x00\x07ActiveX\x00\x165.0 (Windows)-Netscape\x00)\xed\x06\x00\x00\x00@3407d2fbeefadbf85fa0f48bbac8337e026e0669b6be226156fd6fb4d575ef16\x00\xd9A=t&SA=t&SV=t&EV=t&MP3=t&AE=t&VE=t&ACC=t&PR=t&SP=f&SB=f&DEB=f&V=WIN 28,0,0,137&M=Adobe Windows&R=1280x1024&COL=color&AR=1.0&OS=Windows 8&ARCH=x86&L=tr&IME=t&PR32=t&PR64=t&PT=ActiveX&AVD=f&LFD=f&WD=f&TLS=t&ML=5.1&DP=72\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\xca\x00\x00'[:1])[0]
print(packetFormat)
```

Code with variable (Gets the packet from def dataReceived) (it gives false result) (result is 98) (and both packets are same)

```
def dataReceived(this, packet):
    this.package = str(packet)
    packetFormat = unpack('!b', bytes(this.package, "utf-8")[:1])[0]
```

Comment: I just write there false, it needs to be "this.package".

Comment: Can you create a [**complete** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that fails? Otherwise, it is very likely that the problem is somewhere else. Also, the form `bytes('\x02...', 'utf-8')` looks extremely dangerous and prone to break, because it depends on an encoding. Whats wrong with `b'\x02...'`?

Answer (score 3):

Calling `str` on the bytes value that you receive does not do what you think it does.

This is the old, good, behaviour:

```
>>> bs = b'\x02'
>>> struct.unpack('!b', bs)
(2,)
```

In the new code, the `bytes` value is cast to a string:

```
>>> s = str(bs)
```

then it's unpacked:

```
>>> struct.unpack('!b', bytes(s, 'utf-8'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 1
```

Looks like there is something strange about the string value:

```
>>> s
"b'\\x02'"
>>> struct.unpack('!b', bytes(s, 'utf-8')[:1])
(98,)
```

Calling `str` on a `bytes` value gives us the `bytes`' `repr` as a string; to get the `bytes` as a string we need to call the `bytes` value's `decode` method.  Note that your packet data appears to be encoded as latin-1, not utf-8.  This doesn't matter for the first byte, but it does if you want to decode the entire bytestring.

```
>>> s = bs.decode('latin-1')
>>> struct.unpack('!b', bytes(s, 'latin-1'))
(2,)
```

So, don't call `str` on the `bytes` value that you unpack, either decode it or, better still, just leave it as `bytes` and avoid the unnecessary encoding and decoding.  You can decode the bytes to a unicode string and store them on your instance though.

```
def dataReceived(this, packet):
    this.package = packet.decode('latin-1')  # Store packet data as a unicode string
    packetFormat = unpack('!b', packet[:1])[0]
```

Comment: What if I want to have the unpacked data in string?

Comment: I want the original data as a string.